# Python removing specific values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following python dictionary of integers:

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 2: [3, 6, 13],
 3: [1, 2, 3],
 4: [13, 14, 15],
 5: [3, 6],
 6: [6, 13]}
```

I would like to remove the number 6 from both the 5th and 6th entries to the dictionary. I know this is quite simple but I am new to python so all help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as straight-forward as you'd think:

```
dct = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
 2: [3, 6, 13],
 3: [1, 2, 3],
 4: [13, 14, 15],
 5: [3, 6],
 6: [6, 13]}

dct[5].remove(6)
dct[6].remove(6)

print(dct)
```

as `list`s are [*mutable sequence types*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?mutable-sequence-types#mutable-sequence-types) they have a `.remove(element)` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function for this. Given a dictionary `d`:

```
def remover(d, keys, value):
    for k in keys:
        d[k].remove(value)
    return d

remover(d, [5, 6], 6)

# {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
#  2: [3, 6, 13],
#  3: [1, 2, 3],
#  4: [13, 14, 15],
#  5: [3],
#  6: [13]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.remove` on each entry:

```
my_dict[5].remove(6)
my_dict[6].remove(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove values with list comprehensions:

```
>>> d = {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],2: [3, 6, 
13],3: [1, 2, 3],4: [13, 14, 15],5: [3, 6],6: [6, 13]}
>>> d[5] = [x for x in d[5] if x != 6]
>>> d[6] = [x for x in d[6] if x != 6]
>>> d 
{1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 2: [3, 6, 13], 3: [1, 2, 3], 4: [13, 14, 15], 5: [3], 6: [13]}
```